# Change default gdoc placeholder. Chrome extension development

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to change the default gdoc placeholder in the chrome extension development?

Is it possible to do it from a content-script?

It seems like this placeholder is inside the canvas element. Can I have any possibility?

[image]

I was trying to use MutationObserver and find a specific HTML element.

Comment: That approach is not possible.
Uses the [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview).

Comment: Google Doc API will not help as it turned out